# GTM Tags & Triggers only working on Homepage

Tags: google-tag-manager

When viewing different pages of the site, GTM's preview mode "summary" column shows refreshes in its left panel (like here https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/16028728?key=5f8653a2f831cd9c7ea14a2f365112d6 ). Here it's not the case. All the tags and triggers will work on the homepage, but once I view other pages or come back to the home page after, all tracking stops and refreshes aren't recorded https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/16028578?key=b70d15c06419fc26cbd28dadfb8a6b55. I thought it was SPA issue but pages url do change. Any idea why?

Comment: It does look like an SPA issue. Preview is aware of your navigations on an SPA likely due to history change events. And it looks like your SPA engine doesn't change the history in case a page is already cached on the client side or something similar to that. I would suggest pushing an explicit dataLayer event from your SPA's router every time a navigation happens.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Something that has been reoccuring with my new setups for different website are tracking delays. After a day or 2, everything worked fine suddenly. I can't explain it. thanks for your input though.